# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in local works fine but not in server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, c#-4.0

I have to deploy my project from local to the server,in local it works fine but the problem when I try to drop the database "sma" and recreate it,I get this error:

> Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"String was not
>   recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.","ExceptionType":"System.FormatException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)\r\n   at
>   SMA.Entities.Models.SMADBInitializer.Seed(SMAContext context)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action)\r\n

I work on rest API service with asp.net MVC5,it works fine and the database was created with the tables in local(xampp),but I get this error in the server (Windows Server 2012),many tables are created but others not !!
I don't know why did I miss any thing

thanks  a lot for help

UpDATE:

I have modified the web.config file with this line:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
```

and the .Net Globalisation to English (United States) (en-US)

for my code I use

```
 var beginDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2013-04-24 17:47:03");
 dateBirth=DateTime.Parse("2013-04-24 17:47:03")
```

but I still get the same problem :(

Comment: You should include in your message what the string that you are passing in looks like.  In general, if you use the ISO standard formats, such as YYYY-MM-DD, you will minimize such problems.

Comment: It's very likely that locale settings on your development machine are different than on your server. If you don't specify the format for `DateTime.Parse`, it uses the locale settings.

Comment: thanks Gordon and Damir for your replies,in fact yes the time configuartion in the local machine is dd/mm/YYYY(this format I have used in my code) but in the server is dd-MMM-yy

Comment: If I will spicify the data format with DateTime.Parse then I think it will not work on local no??

Comment: SQL Server almost always recognizes dates in the form 'YYYY-MM-DD' and always recognized 'YYYYMMDD'.

Comment: I work with Mysql Xampp :)

Comment: I used this format in my code YYYY-MM-DD still don't get a result

Comment: @hanali, it seems your session may be `DATEFORMAT YDM`.  Run query `DBCC USEROPTIONS` using the same SQL login to verify.

Comment: thanks Dan for your reply bu how can I run this query?

Comment: you are working with c# and sql server, there is no need to pass strings at all. just use an instance of .net DateTime as the value of the parameters passing to sql server and fix all your format problems.

Comment: thanks Zohar but I work with Mysql/Xampp

Comment: @hanali Slightly confused; why are you parsing a date/time string at all? Why not just new up `DateTime` using the relevant ctor? E.g. `new DateTime(2013, 4, 24, 17, 47, 03)`

Comment: Then please remove the sql server tag from your question.